# Overlapping Instagram geographic queries return inconsistent results

Tags: instagram

I'm confused by some Instagram geographic search results I'm seeing. I issue a large query (with lat, lng, and distance=1000) and get one set of photos. I issue a smaller query (with the exact same lat and lng, but distance=800). As expected, the result sets are different, but interestingly the smaller query returns photos that are not returned by the larger query.

To reproduce:

```
curl -s "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=47.58154&lng=-120.66489&distance=1000&client_id={yourid}" | python -mjson.tool | grep link | sort > large_results
curl -s "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=47.58154&lng=-120.66489&distance=800&client_id={yourid}"  | python -mjson.tool | grep link | sort > small_results
```

Diff the two files, and you'll see photos in small_results that are not in large_results.

Is this expected behavior?

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

UPDATE: I submitted this question to Instagram. The response: this behavior is "by design". FYI.